# Why this Asynchronous example works without Dispatcher nor Control.BeginInvoke?

Tags: winforms, silverlight, asynchronous, thread-safety

I was testing an Asynchronous example I wrote in other post, I modified it to show some info in a textbox. what happened next I was not expecting. I don't know why it does not throw an exception when modifying a control from another thread. am I blind or why I don't see it?

here is the example, it works the same for silverlight and WinForms:

```
    int rand=0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Func<Action<int, int>, Action<int>> DownloadDataInBackground = (callback) =>
    {
        return (c) =>
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.google.com/search?q={0}", c));
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e2) =>
            {
                callback(c, e2.Result.Length);
            };
            client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        };
    };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int callid = rand++;
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing CallID #{0}", callid);
        DownloadDataInBackground((c3, r3) =>this.textBox1.Text+=string.Format("The result for the callid {0} is {1} \n", c3, r3))(callid);
    }
```

Tap the button pretty fast, it wont fail.

your help will be very appreciated.

Edit: added picture showing that windows forms always execute controls modification from the main thread, but, why if it is supposed to be another one?
[image: winfors mainthread]

Comment: If you ran it enough, you would get a problem. It would appear to be "random".

Comment: yes i tested, click more than 150 times and it will fail, then the question now is, why it takes too long to fail?

Comment: Probably what you are doing actually has a small chance of hitting problems, because not much else is happening with the UI when the update comes in. But incidentally; 1 in 150 is a very high rate of failure.

Comment: that was silverlight, Winforms does not seem to have the same issue, I click more than 1600 times, after some minutes it finish executing every thread successfully. so the question remains the same, why it does not fail, at least in winForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer to why your code doesn't fail in the way you expect it to is that the `WebClient` invokes its events on the UI thread.  Hence you aren't modifying your control on a different thread as you seem to imagine you are.

Comment: I just read that only two clases execute events on main thread that is BackgroundWorker and WebClient. Thanks. I was starting to think I was entering another dimension where threads could modify controls of the main thread.